# How do I manage the error "OpenSSL v1.1.1 ssl_choose_client_version unsupported protocol"?

Tags: openssl, openvpn

While trying to connect to a VPN via `openvpn` I get the following error from `openssl`

```
Tue Oct 30 11:34:16 2018 WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
... several more lines
Tue Oct 30 11:34:17 2018 OpenSSL: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
Tue Oct 30 11:34:17 2018 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
Tue Oct 30 11:34:17 2018 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
Tue Oct 30 11:34:17 2018 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Tue Oct 30 11:34:17 2018 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Tue Oct 30 11:34:17 2018 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

This error does not arise when using OpenSSL 1.1.0h.

- Why does this error arise after upgrading the `openssl` libraries?
- How do I manage around this recurring problem?
- Is there a way to make this work by giving some flags to `openvpn` CLI instead of downgrading `openssl`?

OS: Debian Sid

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**You don't have to downgrade OpenSSL.**

With the introduction of openssl version 1.1.1 in Debian the defaults are set to more secure values by default. This is done in the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf config file. At the end of the file there is:

```
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
```

Debian now require as minimum the TLS 1.2 version instead TLS 1.0. If the other side does not support TLS 1.2 or higher you will get some connection errors.

**I recommend  upgrade openvpn on server to newer version which support TLS 1.2.**.

Second options (not much secure) is modify MinProcotol to TLSv1 or TLSv1.1.

Comment: Wonderful. I had to use `TLSv1`. Its very sad to say that our institute server runs top of the line hardware with terribly shamefully outdated software. :( Their setup is such that they are unable to update to openvpn. I'll try talking to them once more, but chances are very less.

Comment: If anybody gets this error while using nodemailer, try using node v10 only without changing any ssl or tls configuration

Answer (score 18):

**You don't have to downgrade OpenSSL *or* change the system default.**

Instead of modifying /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf you can just configure the openvpn
client to configure libssl with a different minimum protocol version. The option
is `--tls-version-min` or `tls-version-min` in a config file.

It's still preferable to upgrade the server but this is a better way to deal with a temporary version skew.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, it is far less invasive than the solution in the accepted one.

Comment: I have experienced that tls-version-min in a config file is simply ignored by openvpn 1.1.1d.

Comment: @JensMunk same problem. More info about it: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=933177

Answer (score 3):

You can even directly override the system default e.g. by using:

```
tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1"
```

to have a basic configuration that matches normal OpenSSL defaults. Note that OpenVPN normally sets a more restricted cipher list (see man page).