# How to download a webpage that uses TLS v1.0 using wget or curl

Tags: curl, wget

I want to download the following webpage from the command line:
https://lccn.loc.gov/

But this page uses an old version of TLS (v1.0 according to Google Chome security tab), and neither `curl` not `wget` can download it.  They return these errors (respectively):

```
curl: (35) error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol

OpenSSL: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

How can I download this webpage from the command line?

Comment: If you are using Debian or Ubuntu, or possibly a related distro like Mint, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058362/openssl-v1-1-1-ssl-choose-client-version-unsupported-protocol https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61568215/openssl-v1-1-1-ubuntu-20-tlsv1-no-protocols-available https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62357205/openssl-cant-establish-ssl-connection-because-unsupported-protocol . Otherwise specify what versions and builds (including underlying stacks) you are using.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: perfect!  That was it.  I was using Ubuntu 20.04, which changed the minimum acceptable TLS version.  The solution I preferred was to use: `wget --ciphers=DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1`.  If you enter your comment as an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks!