# Drush "demands" SSL connection to database

Tags: mysql, drupal

```
drush sql-dump > bdd.sql
mysqldump: Got error: 2026: SSL connection error: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol when trying to connect
 [error]  Database dump failed
```

Drupal is perfectly working with its database and I can connect to the remote database with the mysql client but drush keeps trying to connect via SSL and I don't know how to prevent it. I created a my.cnf in my user folder trying to disable SSL but it seems to ignore it.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058362/openssl-v1-1-1-ssl-choose-client-version-unsupported-protocol help?

Comment: @ceejayoz nope, they propose just changing the whole machine SSL security. That wouldn't work for me.

Comment: which version of drush do you use?

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk 9.4.0

Answer (score 0):

In the long run, it is a much better idea to resolve your SSL issues. But, there is a way to get drush to work if you're stuck.

For some of drush's sql commands, there is an `--extra` parameter where you can provide MySQL cli parameters. So, you can pass MySQL's `--skip-ssl` param:

```
drush sql:cli --extra=--skip-ssl
```

Note that the `--extra` param is not available on some drush sql commands, such as `sql:drop` and `sql:create`, at least in drush 9.