# ssl.SSLError - unsupported protocol?

Tags: mysql, ssl, openssl

The error looks like this in my python code:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'x.x.x.x:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1108)
```

SQL error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1108)
```

Do you know what to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python ssl ssl.SSLError: \[SSL: UNSUPPORTED\_PROTOCOL\] unsupported protocol (\_ssl.c:590)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330919/python-ssl-ssl-sslerror-ssl-unsupported-protocol-unsupported-protocol-ssl)